# How can we perform cross browser testing using BDD in Squish Tool

Tags: python, automation, bdd, squish

I am working in squish tool and using BDD framework with python support. I have written a feature file where I have to perform cross browser testing using the browser - IE, Chrome, Firefox. Can any one tell me the configuration and the set up needed to achieve the same

Comment: Please clarify "cross browser" testing. Do you mean that you need to run the tests with each browser, separately, or that a single test needs to automate multiple different browsers at the same time (or one after the other)?

Comment: I need to run one after the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Configuring squishserver](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rg-cmdline.html#rg-squishrunner-cli--config) (this link mentions configuring squishrunner, but in reality this configures squishserver, don't be confused by that) to use a specific web browser:

```
cd squish_dir
bin/squishserver --config setDefaultWebBrowser firefox
```

Other possible values instead of "firefox" are "google-chrome", "ie", "safari", "edge", "chromium-based".

This command should be executed before the next test suite/case execution, that should use a different web browser, is being started.